# Wi-Fi 6 AX200 and DisplayPort issue on HP Omen 15-en0012na

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

Wi-Fi 6 AX200 and DisplayPort issue on my new HP Omen 15-en0012na, I have an Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX200 Wi-Fi card installed.

The issue is that whenever I use an external display with Mini DisplayPort connected and restart or put computer to sleep and then wake it up, the Wi-Fi card becomes inactive and I have to disconnect the screen and fully restart the machine.

Solutions I've tried so far:

1. Updating the BIOS
2. Updating all the drivers from the official HP driver page
3. Installing Intel drivers for the Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX200 card
4. Disabling the option for the PC to be able to put the Wi-Fi adapter to sleep
5. Changing MIMO Power Save Mode to No SMPS
6. In advanced power options, disabling the PC's ability to put the hard drive to sleep
7. Uninstalling Omen Command Centre
8. Checking the BIOS options for useful options regarding the issue

I've checked the Event Log in Windows and I found these errors messages:

> Miniport Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, {7f01b158-9352-4e17-b94a-457b5c425fcb}, had event Fatal error: The miniport has failed a power transition to operational power
> The local Bluetooth adapter has failed in an undetermined manner and will not be used. The driver has been unloaded

The thing that would make the most sense to do in my case would be to post on the HP Support Forums, but after I did that they deleted my post without any warning or trace that it had existed... and we need to publicly archive this kind of behaviour so I came here. Hope this is the place for this kind of issue.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There is really only three possibilities here... A driver issue (unlikely since you installed the Intel drivers), OS corruption, or a faulty card. The OS corruption could be tested with a live Linux distro as the Intel drivers are baked into the stock kernel in modern distros, boot Linux with your stuff connected and put the PC to sleep, then wake it up, give it 30-60 seconds for Network Manager to initialize and see if it works, if it does it's likely OS corruption. If it still fails, consider a new AX200 card, they are about $20-$25 online, I just put one in my Dell G3.

Comment: I have the same issue on two hp omen 15-en0023dx that I own (which also have the Intel AX200 wifi) . If it is a hardware issue it exists in many of them! Hopefuly it's just a driver problem. Disconnecting the displayport and then putting the computer to sleep and waking up, then doing the Device Manager "Scan for Hardware Changes" brings the wifi device back. I have installed all the updates from firmware to graphics drivers from NVidia and also all the AMD updates but nothing has resolved it.

Comment: I know for a fact that this is a software issue, since I tried multiple units, also without bios update this issue doesn't occur, so it's a bios issue. Also only reproducible with mini display port.

Comment: @NikasNikis I just tested tested installing the previous two BIOS versions for my 15-en0023dx. It means I have tested with 3 different BIOS versions. Same issue on all of them. So in my case I cannot conclude that it is a BIOS issue.

Comment: This HP Omen model support DisplayPort via USB-C. I worked around the issue by buying a USB-C to DisplayPort cable and connecting via the USB-C port instead of the mini-DisplayPort. The Wi-Fi no longer disappears when the computer wakes up from sleep.

Answer (score 0):

I actually have the same issue on my 15-en0175nd. Maybe it's a common issue on all these models? Really bizarre problem. I was able to resolve it by doing what Marquez said:

> Disconnecting the displayport and then putting the computer to sleep and waking up, then doing the Device Manager "Scan for Hardware Changes" brings the wifi device back.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1181781)